# How can I share things to other apps on a Windows 10 App by JS?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-store-apps, windows, windows-10

I am creating a Windows 10 hosted Web App following the guideline [here](http://microsoftedge.github.io/WebAppsDocs/en-US/win10/CreateHWA.htm). I have a button on my App, which for Android, would lauch the native sharing dialogue. I guess Windows 10 should have something similar, so that users can share the page URL to other apps like Facebook and Twitter whewn they find the page interesting. I am looking at [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh871363.aspx) but the links are dead. Any examples or documentations about how I can achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On the following location you can find example code (JS, C# and C++) how to share data/content with another app in Windows 10.

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/sharesource